# apply a function to the DF if a column satisfies a condition

Tags: r

Hi i have a function that needs to run be on the columns (a,b,c) if the column d satisfies a condition.

so for instance.

dataframe

```
  A      B       C    D
77.66   5.54    889   1
65.3    4.2     67    1
69.47   0.92    55    2
```

So i want to run this function if the column D == 1

```
sum_mean <- function (A,C){ 
    sum(A*C)/sum(C)
    }
```

else

run this function if the column D == 2

```
sum_sd <- function (B,C){
  sqrt(sum(B^2*C)/sum(C))
}
```

How can i achieve it in r

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
  with(df, c(sum_mean(A,C), sum_sd(B,C))[D])
  #[1] 76.395341 76.395341  5.310653
```

Or use `ifelse`

```
  with(df, ifelse(D==1,  sum_mean(A,C),sum_sd(B,C)))
 #[1] 76.395341 76.395341  5.310653
```